Why does `git clone --depth 1` leave packfiles?
I am trying to clone a repository with a lot of blobs in its history, and would like to only download the files at a specific commit without any added overhead or redundancy.
When trying git clone --depth 1, the .git directory becomes quite large.  This appears to be because of a large packfile, whose file size corresponds to the size reported by git when it is Receiving objects:.  Inspecting the packfile with git verify-pack suggests it contains a large amount of blob information.
However, trying git clone --filter=blob:none still results in a similarly large packfile listing blobs.
My expectation would be that --depth 1 shouldn't be downloading any history, and filter=blob:none shouldn't be downloading any blob history.
So why is my .git directory being populated with packfile overhead for a shallow clone?
I am wondering if this is perhaps the initial compressed download of the single commit I checked out - but even so, how can I prevent this redundant file from persisting?
For specific reference, the repository I am cloning is ARM-software/CMSIS_5.
This started out as a question about shallow submodules and only downloading files at a specific commit without overhead, but the packfile overhead appears to pertain to cloning in general so I figured I'd start here.

git clone creates a repository, which consists of blobs. The files you are want are created from blobs. If you only want the files, you don't want a repository, but perhaps an archive (created with git archive from the repository).

In this case, I do still want the directory to maintain its repository identity (ultimately, because I wish to use it as a submodule, without explicit need for the submodule's history).  If the files I want are being created from the blobs, is there a way to "prune" the blobs (ie. the packfile) once the checked-out files are created?

If I run git clone --filter blob:none https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS_5/, the resulting repository is only 78M in size. That's teeny. It seems like things are working as expected. Without the filter, the repository is about 313M. (fwiw, I am using git version 2.45.2)

@chepner it sounds like you may not be familiar with  partial clones.

@larsks Yes, --filter=blob:none certainly is filtering out blobs (and --depth 1 successfully clones shallowly; git 2.43.0).  My question, rather, stems from trying to understand why a single packfile in .git/objects/pack/ makes up ~30% of that storage space (especially for --depth 1, where I expect no history), and why that packfile contains blobs (especially for --filter=blob:none, where I expect no historic blobs).

You need the blobs that correspond to the files in your working tree. There are roughly 3225 files when I clone the repository, and there are 2807 blobs (maybe due to duplication or something, I haven't checked any closer, but that all seems reasonable and expected).

@larsks I believe I understand. If you propose an answer which describes the necessity of these blobs when they are redundant to the current working tree, I will gladly mark it as a solution.

I have posted a (loose) follow-up to this question from the perspective of submodules here, for anyone following the breadcrumbs.


Inspecting the packfile with git verify-pack suggests it contains a large amount of blob information.

When you run...
git clone --filter blob:none --depth 1 https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS_5

...you are still checking out a working copy from the repository. The repository in question has over 3000 files in it:
$ find * -type f -print | wc -l
3225

Since file content is stored in blobs, that means that regardless of the blob:none filter, git will still need to transfer the blobs that correspond to the files in the HEAD commit, so we would expect to see a similar magnitude of blobs in the packfiles. And indeed after running the above command, we see:
$ git verify-pack -v .git/objects/pack/pack-b0279f34420775288c089456dfc84f2697570837.pack |
  grep blob | wc -l
2807


If you don't check out a working copy (e.g., you clone with --bare), the resulting repository will not contain any blobs:
$ git clone --bare --filter blob:none --depth=1 https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS_5/
$ find CMSIS_5.git/objects/pack/ -name '*.pack' | xargs -n1 git verify-pack -v | grep blob | wc -l
0


Thank you, @larsks.  I think the missing piece for me was understanding that in order to populate the working directory, it first must be obtained in a packfile.  I was looking for a way to (automatically) delete the redundant packfile once the working tree is populated, but I believe this would make sense only in the specific case of a shallow, static clone, and so I can understand why it is not a feature of git.
